# "Command not Found" Errors when Sourcing my Env

Tags: bash, cron, environment-variables

I keep a good copy of my env in a file `/root/.env` which I import when I use cron jobs because I use them to run `Expect` Scripts which won't run without TERM and a few others(?). I do so as such:
`set -o allexport; source /root/.env; set +o allexport`

It works, however Cron also emails me the contents of the .env file as a list of *Command Not Found* errors:

```
/root/.env: line 4: 34:ln=01: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 36:mh=00:pi=40: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 33:so=01: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 35:do=01: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 35:bd=40: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 33: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 01:cd=40: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 33: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 01:or=40: command not found
/root/.env: line 4: 31: command not found
```

Also this one:
  `/root/.env: line 18: fg: no job control`

How do I get it to stop trying to interpret the file's contents as commands?

Edit: Here's the .env:

```
root@____:/home/____# cat ~/.env
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=vt100
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SUDO_USER=abdmin
SUDO_UID=1000
USERNAME=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PWD=/home/abdmin
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
HOME=/root
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
LOGNAME=root
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
SUDO_GID=1000
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: Those look like `$TERMCAP` components.  Are you sure everything in your `.env` file is quoted properly?  Can you post your `.env` file here?

Comment: @jwodder Updated! Is it because of the semicolons?

Comment: @KuboMD: Yes, reasonably it is. the `env` output is not suitable for sourcing into a bash program without modifications. How about creating a file with the variables you actually need?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, I think going by elimination may work. I removed the LS_COLORS line which allowed my programs to run while not generating errors. However I still get the "no job control" error  that seems to point to the end of the file. Not sure which variable it's related to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to helpful comments, I was able to remove the variables I didn't need until cron stopped complaining.

```
command not found
```

Errors were silenced by removing the `LS_COLORS` line from my .env file. The `fg: no job control` error, as I understand it, was caused by these two lines:

```
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
```

because the shell was interpreting `%s` as `fg`. 
**This is unique to my case**, but it got my cron jobs working with my expect scripts, so I'm satisfied with this outcome.

Comment: To successfully source those variables, you simply need to quote their values, e.g. `LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"` (due to the spaces).